# "Return" does not return anything in Spyder. It works fine with other IDE

Tags: python, function, spyder

I just moved to spyder for Python and the return function doesn't seem to work:

```
def test():
   return 2
test()
```

The IPython console is empty. If I use print instead of return it works fine. Any idea?

I use python 3.7 with Spyder 4.1.5

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are not printing the value. Use `print(test())`

Comment: Some IDEs autoprint variable content like in the IDLE if you just input the name of a function and call it or the name of a variable. Spyder does not and your code does not print anything itself

Comment: @MelvinAbraham Thanks! But this is supposed to work with just return. It works on Jupiter and it works on my colleagues' Spyder.

Comment: Jupyter notebook and python console are just REPL not an IDE. They don't not specifically require a `print()` function but when you run a python program using an IDE or just by using something like `python3 script.py`, they won't print out anything unless asked to.

Comment: As a nicety, and because they are environments where you run lines of code interactlively, Jupyter and the Python REPL automatically print the return value of the functions you run (if it isn't None) or of anything you evaluate. You should print it yourself if you want anything to be displayed in other environments.

Comment: If you like my answer/ it works can you accept it so i know otherwise ill delete it so im not wasting others time who want to see the answer to this question ( they may have a similiar issue)

Answer (score 2):

The editor is handling your code as a normal python script which means statements ala
`test()`
don't print their result. Instead you will need to do something with the value you are returning E.g. assign it to a variable or print it.

That you get the result of something displayed immediately is a special function of the python console and not normal python behaviour.

To actually print the result you have to call `print(test())`
so try this:

```
 def test():
return 2
enter    
 >>press enter
print(test()
 >>press enter
```