# view of the return value in spyder

Tags: console, spyder

related to this question:
["Return" does not return anything in Spyder. It works fine with other IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64932471/return-does-not-return-anything-in-spyder-it-works-fine-with-other-ide/64955741#64955741)

```
def test():
 return 2
test()
```

is it possible to see the value of "2" somewhere without the print-statement? Like in the Variable explorer or in the console 1/A?

I think I miss a setting or check in a checkbox?

I use Spyder 4.0.1 and Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to enclose you last statement (i.e. `test()`) in a `print` to see its return value printed in the console:

```
print(test())
```

Or you can assign `test()` to a variable to see its result in the Variable Explorer:

```
a = test()
```